# Understanding a question on linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The question is

> Does there exist a vector space $V$ over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and three vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2, \vec{v}_3$ in $V$ such that the 4 vectors $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \vec{v}_3, \vec{v}_4 = \vec{v}_1 − 2\vec{v}_2 + \vec{v}_3$ are linearly
>   independent? Justify your answer.

Solving for $$a \cdot \vec{v}_1 + b\cdot\vec{v}_2+ c\cdot\vec{v}_3 + d\cdot\vec{v}_4 = \vec{0}$$
gives $a = c, b = -2a$ for the system to have 0 for each coefficient but I'm not sure where to go from there, mainly because I don't really understand what the question is looking for.

Comment: You have written out a linear dependence, so no.

Comment: Yeah I clarified that, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: There's nothing else to do.  Those vectors are linearly dependent, by virtue of their defining relation.

Comment: Why don't you subtract $v_4$ from both sides to get:
$$v_1-2v_2+v_3-v_4=0$$
And thus you have $a,b,c,d$ so that at least one of the coefficients are non-zero?

Comment: Ah okay, the triviality of the question confused me, thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot $d=-a$ and to say that $a$ is any real number (you only needed to pick one though, since would rescale both sides and $a*0=0$), but otherwise you are done. Your linear dependence works for all possible choices in the question. All $V$ and all $v_{1,2,3}$ in that $V$.